# How to index System Setting in Kupfer?

Tags: launcher, system-settings, kupfer

I am running *Ubuntu* 14.04. and installed *Kupfer* 208.

[image: Kupfer]

For some reason I cannot search and launch the applications from *System Settings* such as *Display* or *Appearance*. The *Unity* launcher finds all of them.

[image: System Settings]

I looked through the settings and list of plug-ins but could not find out how to index the *System Setting*.

Comment: As best I can tell, this is handled by Kupfer core. There is not a plugin that obviously applies.  FWIW I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (clean install, not an upgrade, in case that's relevant) and Kupfer v208, and system settings show up in the first box when I type their names.

Comment: I dug through the source a bit looking for clues, but ubiquitous references to Kupfer's own internal 'settings' objects makes it a tough hunt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just upgraded and ran into this problem. Run the following commands in the terminal to fix the issue (for the logged in user only):

Copy launcher files for control centre items to user specific directory for editing

```
cp /usr/share/applications/unity-* /usr/share/applications/system-config-printer.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Remove attributes preventing the launchers appearing outside of Unity

```
sed -i 's/OnlyShowIn=Unity;//' ~/.local/share/applications/unity-*
sed -i 's/NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;/NotShowIn=KDE;/' ~/.local/share/applications/system-config-printer.desktop
```

Comment: Why should it appear outside Unity while the user IS in Unity?

Comment: @JJD - I am in Xubuntu and have the same problem with Kupfer in Xfce, but also [the same problem with the Xfce launcher xfce4-appfinder](http://askubuntu.com/q/551384/47206). Is the Unity launcher able to see what initially Kupfer was not?

Comment: This worked for me for Kupfer and XFCE settings. Copied to $HOME/.local/share/applications and ran sed -i 's/OnlyShowIn=XFCE;//' $HOME/.local/share/applications/xfce*

Comment: Still works for Unity on Ubuntu 16.04.